# Signup in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an Android App in React-Native and I need to do the SignUp Method.

I use PouchDB/CouchDB for the DB.

This is a part of  my signup page code:

Why in your opinion it doesn't go?? 
Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194818/discussion-on-question-by-jack23-signup-in-react-native).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method call does not match the method signature.

```
// Method signature
static createUser(identity, FirstName, LastName, FiscalCode /*, Password*/)

// Incorrect Method call
User.createUser({identity: identity, FirstName: this.props.FirstName,LastName: this.props.LastName,FiscalCode: this.props.FiscalCode})

// Correct Method call
User.createUser(identity, this.props.FirstName, this.props.LastName, this.props.FiscalCode)
```

Also, in the if condition you are checking for class properties when they should be in state.

```
// Incorrect
            utility.isEmpty(this.Password) ||
            utility.isEmpty(this.PasswordRepeat)  

// Corrected

            utility.isEmpty(this.state.Password) ||
            utility.isEmpty(this.state.PasswordRepeat)
```